# Implementing Otsu binarization for faded images of documents

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I'm trying to implement Otsu binarization technique on document images such as the one shown:

[image]

Could someone please tell me how to implement the code in MATLAB?

Comment: It is present in Matlab by default, see `graythresh`

Comment: The function `graythresh` from the Image Processing Toolbox computers Otsu's threshold.

Comment: While Otsu' being one of the best thresholding technique, in a case like yours - it might be more prudent to apply adaptive thresholding. Read [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/adaptive-thresholding-for-liver-segmentation-using-matlab/1744#1744) and [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm) for some elementary reference and ask question post that.

Answer (score 7):

Taken from [Otsu's method on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
```

**Step 1.** Compute histogram and probabilities of each intensity level.

```
nbins = 256; % Number of bins
counts = imhist(I,nbins); % Each intensity increments the histogram from 0 to 255
p = counts / sum(counts); % Probabilities
```

**Step 2.** Set up initial omega_i(0) and mu_i(0)

```
omega1 = 0;
omega2 = 1;
mu1 = 0;
mu2 = mean(I(:));
```

**Step 3.** Step through all possible thresholds from 0 to maximum intensity (255)

**Step 3.1** Update omega_i and mu_i

**Step 3.2** Compute sigma_b_squared

```
for t = 1:nbins
    omega1(t) = sum(p(1:t));
    omega2(t) = sum(p(t+1:end));
    mu1(t) = sum(p(1:t).*(1:t)');
    mu2(t) = sum(p(t+1:end).*(t+1:nbins)');
end

sigma_b_squared_wiki = omega1 .* omega2 .* (mu2-mu1).^2; % Eq. (14)
sigma_b_squared_otsu = (mu1(end) .* omega1-mu1) .^2 ./(omega1 .* (1-omega1)); % Eq. (18)
```

**Step 4** Desired threshold corresponds to the location of maximum of sigma_b_squared

```
[~,thres_level_wiki] = max(sigma_b_squared_wiki);
[~,thres_level_otsu] = max(sigma_b_squared_otsu);
```

There are some differences between the wiki-version eq. (14) in Otsu and the eq. (18), and I don't why. But the `thres_level_otsu` correspond to the MATLAB's implementation `graythresh(I)`

Comment: thanks for this, really helpful! Could you please tell how to implement the sauvola thresholding algorithm as well? I cant figure out how to dynamically choose the values of k and R in it.Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not familiar with sauvola thresholding, but if you wan't help with this you should start a new thread with this question. Small tip: provide the relevant sources for potential answers if you want more attention to your thread.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the following statements:                 [~,thres_level_wiki] = max(sigma_b_squared_wiki);
[~,thres_level_otsu] = max(sigma_b_squared_otsu);     saying statement is unbalanced.Could you please help?

Comment: Unbalanced error occurs when then number of opening parenthesis doesn't match the closing parenthesis, and that is not the case. Maybe an older version of MATLAB that doesn't support tilde-sign as dummy value.

Comment: How can i correct this? Could i place a zero instead of ~ in the statement?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with MATLAB you should look into a beginners guide. ~ can be replaced with any arbitrary variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function `graythresh` in Matlab implements the Otsu method, what you have to do is convert your image to grayscale and then use the `im2bw` function to binarize the image using the threhsold level returned by  `graythresh`.

To convert your image `I` to grayscale you can use the following code:

```
I = im2uint8(I);
if size(I,3) ~= 1
    I = rgb2gray(I);
end;
```

To get the binary image `Ib` using the Otsu's method, use the following code:

```
Ib = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
```

You should get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting out with what your initial question was implementing the OTSU thresolding its true that MATLAB's `graythresh` function is based on that method 
The OTSU's method considers the threshold value as the valley between two peaks that is one of the foreground pixels and the other of the background pixels

Pertaining to your image which seems like a historical manuscript found this [paper](http://www.teilar.gr/dbData/Dimosieyseis/03-com.pdf) that compares all the methods that could be used for thresholding document images

You can also download and read up sauvola thresholding from [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.98.880)

Good luck with its implementation =)

Answer (score 1):

Corrected MATLAB Implementation (for 2d matrix)

```
function [T] = myotsu(I,N);

% create histogram

nbins = N; 

[x,h] = hist(I(:),nbins);

% calculate probabilities

p = x./sum(x);

% initialisation

om1 = 0; 

om2 = 1; 

mu1 = 0; 

mu2 = mode(I(:));


for t = 1:nbins,

    om1(t) = sum(p(1:t));
    om2(t) = sum(p(t+1:nbins));
    mu1(t) = sum(p(1:t).*[1:t]);
    mu2(t) = sum(p(t+1:nbins).*[t+1:nbins]);

end

    sigma = (mu1(nbins).*om1-mu1).^2./(om1.*(1-om1));


idx = find(sigma == max(sigma));

T = h(idx(1));
```